# how to return the current object?

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

in code igniter you can type:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   echo $row->title;
   echo $row->name;
   echo $row->body;
}
```

i guess that the query method returns the object it's part of. am i correct?

if i am, how do you type the line where it returns the object?

so what i wonder is how it looks like inside the query method for the above code to be functional.

```
public function query($sql) {
    // some db logic here with the $sql and saves the values to the properties (title, name and body)

    return X
}
```

with other words, what should X be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is located in /system/database/DB_driver.php:244

On a successful query, it returns a new db result object for the database driver (probably) set in your application's database config.

ex: CI_DB_mysql_result (located in /system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_result.php );

> with other words, what should X be?

```
$driver         = $this->load_rdriver();
$RES            = new $driver();
$RES->conn_id   = $this->conn_id;
$RES->result_id = $this->result_id;
```

from DB_driver.php:366

Answer (score 2):

I havn't read the CodeIgniter source code, but it might be reasonable to assume that `$query` is some kind of class representing a db result, so it might very well be a `return $this;`

It could also be something like: `return new Db_ResultSet($data)` or similar.